# Php Elastic Search Sort By Geo distance

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I am trying to sort by distance in km
my field type is
`"location": { "properties": { "lat": { "type": "float" }, "lon": { "type": "float" } } },`

in my index its store like  `"location": { "lon": 72.9814762, "lat": 33.7013063 },`

and in query

Comment: You should probably map your location to be a [geo-point data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html). I'm not sure if this can be auto-mapped though, you might need to manually define the mappings.

Answer (score 0):

@apokryfos is right, you have to map the data as a geo point.
After that you'll be able to sort on _geo_distance

```
"sort": [
    {
      "_geo_distance": {
        "coords": {
          "lat": -27.87,
          "lon": -54.43
        },
        "order": "asc",
        "unit": "km",
        "mode": "min",
        "distance_type": "arc",
        "ignore_unmapped": true
      }
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do your mapping manually. Please find example of mapping below (works on ES 7.4.0). First command creates the index, second command maps 2 fields (one field of type geo_point) and third command retrieves the mapping info.

```
> curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" 
> "http://localhost:9200/my_helloworld_location"
> 
> curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" 
> "http://localhost:9200/my_helloworld_location/_mapping/doc?include_type_name=true"
> -d ' {     "properties":{     "locationName":{  
>     "type":"text",
>     "fields":{  
>     "keyword":{  
>       "ignore_above":20,
>       "type":"keyword"
>     }    }   },    "location":{  
>     "type":"geo_point",
>     "fields":{  
>     "keyword":{  
>       "ignore_above":20,
>       "type":"keyword"
>     }    }   }  }   }'  
> 

> curl -X GET -H "Content-Type:application/json" 
> "http://localhost:9200/my_helloworld_location/_mapping?pretty=true"
```